# Numerical error in NIntegrate and NDsolve

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration, warning-messages

```
Table[sbar = 100;
theta = 1;
h = 5/10;
w2 = i;
 nu = 7/10;
al[t_] = sbar Sin[w2 t];
rho[t_] = 1 + nu Sin[w2 t];
r[x_, t_] = -theta (1 - x) D[rho[t], t] // Simplify;
 r1[x_, t_] = -theta x (1 - x) al[t] rho[t] (1 - 2 x + h (4 x - 3)) //
Simplify;

 (eqs = Subtract @@@ {D[v[x, t], 
        t] == -al[t] x (1 - x) D[(x + h (1 - 2 x)) v[x, t], 
          x] + (x (1 - x)/(2 rho[t])) D[v[x, t], x, x] + r[x, t] +
         r1[x, t], v[x, 0] == 0, v[0, t] == 0, v[1, t] == 0} // 
    Together // Numerator // Expand // Simplify) // TableForm;

 vsol = v /. 
  First@NDSolve[Thread[eqs == 0], v, {x, 0, 1}, {t, 0, 100 Pi/w2}(*,
 MaxSteps\[Rule]10^5,MaxStepSize\[Rule]{.0002,.04},
 StartingStepSize\[Rule]{.0001,.01}*), WorkingPrecision -> 30];
 nint1 = NIntegrate[2 vsol[x, t], {x, 0, 1}, {t, 52 Pi/w2, 54 Pi/w2}, 
MaxRecursion -> 20];
 Integrate[
2 (1 - x) rho[t], {x, 0, 1}, {t, 52 Pi/w2, 54 Pi/w2}]/(2 Pi/w2) + 
nint1/(2 Pi/w2), {i, 10, 90, 40}]
```

Please suggest me how to remove the numerical errors, clearly the answer which is coming is clearly off and absurd.

Comment: It would be helpful if you added a few more words of what you think the problem is and what you expected. Also, it might be useful for you to simplify your code. When I look at it and see a `Table[...,{i,420,420,420}]` I am not sure I want to spend time on this.

Comment: Sir the answer was expected to be around 2. I wrote table like this because i needed values for various i. But for i larger than 400, my answers are not correct. You can ignore this table thing because i just wanted to calculate for one particular i.

Comment: For your consideration, i have removed the table and updated the question.

Comment: You give equations with machine precision (approx. 16) and then define WorkingPrecision->30.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take the periodicity of the diffequation into account. Since t only occurs in Sin or Cos with minimal 10 t, you have peroidicity of 2 Pi/10. NDSolve for high t would be very unreliable; integrate within lower period (But not from the beginning t==0 because of disturbing effects due to initial conditions). Rationalize parameters.

```
sbar = 420;
theta = 1;
h = 1/2;
w2 = 10;
nu = 7/10;
al[t_] = sbar Sin[2 w2 t];
rho[t_] = 1 + nu Sin[w2 t]; 
r[x_, t_] = -theta (1 - x) D[rho[t], t] // Simplify;
r1[x_, t_] = -theta x (1 - x) al[t] rho[t] (1 - 2 x + h (4 x - 3)) // 
 Simplify;

(eqs = Subtract @@@ {D[v[x, t], 
       t] == -al[t] x (1 - x) D[(x + h (1 - 2 x)) v[x, t], 
         x] + (x (1 - x)/(2 rho[t])) D[v[x, t], x, x] + r[x, t] + 
       r1[x, t], v[x, 0] == 0, v[0, t] == 0, v[1, t] == 0} // 
   Together // Numerator // Expand // Simplify) // TableForm

vsol = v /. 
  First@NDSolve[Thread[eqs == 0], v, {x, 0, 1}, {t, 0, 3}, 
MaxSteps -> 10^5, MaxStepSize -> {.0002, .04}, 
StartingStepSize -> {.0001, .01}]
```

Periodiity in t for all x shown in graphic. Integrating from t=2 Pi/w2 to t=4 Pi/w2 should yield the same as your given range.

```
Manipulate[
  Plot[{vsol[x, t], vsol[x, t + 2 Pi/w2], vsol[x, t + 4   Pi/w2]}, {t, 
  2 Pi/w2, 4 Pi/w2}, PlotPoints -> 100], {{x, 1/2}, 0, 1}]

Plot3D[vsol[x, t], {x, 0, 1}, {t, 2 Pi/w2, 4 Pi/w2}, PlotRange -> All,
 PlotPoints -> 50]

nint1 = NIntegrate[2 vsol[x, t], {x, 0, 1}, {t, 2 Pi/w2, 4 Pi/w2}]

(*   -0.00674974   *)

(*   Error message: ....NIntegrate obtained -0.00674974 and 6.36785*10^-8 for the integral \
and error estimates   *)
```

If you are not satisfied with the estimated error of 6 10^-8, you have to use higher WorkingPrecision. But this takes very long and may crash due to not enough memory.

```
Integrate[
 2 (1 - x) rho[t], {x, 0, 1}, {t, 42 Pi/w2, 44 Pi/w2}]/(2 Pi/w2) + 
nint1/(2 Pi/w2)

(*   0.989257   *)
```

Comment: Thank you so much!!!!!! but the periodicity for small t is not strong. I wanted to avoid the initial disturbances and thats why integrating over large time. I will look at it. Many thanks.

Comment: Could you also please mention that while I am integrating over x and try to plot it for time only. It is not able to integrate .
Plot[{NIntegrate[vsol[x, t], {x, 0, 1}]}, {t, 2 Pi/w2, 4 Pi/w2}]

Comment: Tell NIntegrate not to try symbolicProcessing for that interpolating function vsol `Plot[NIntegrate[vsol[x, t], {x, 0, 1}, 
  Method -> {Automatic, "SymbolicProcessing" -> 0}], {t, 2 Pi/w2, 
  4 Pi/w2}] `

Comment: Sir, could you please look the edited one, this also contains error and give me wrong solution.

Comment: On my older version 8.0 this works well. As alternative you can try `wsol[x_?NumericQ, t_?NumericQ] = vsol[x, t]; nint[t_?NumericQ] := NIntegrate[wsol[x, t], {x, 0, 1}]; Plot[nint[t], {t, 2 Pi/w2, 4 Pi/w2}] `